# Is it bad to average several MAEs calculated from chunks of a big test dataset?

Tags: python, keras, convolutional-neural-network, metric, mean

In my regression problem, I am using Mean Absolute Error (MAE) as a metric for my network. My test dataset is too big to fit in memory, so I am reading the test dataset in chunks and then Keras' `evaluate()` the chunk.

```
with pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', chunksize=chunk_size, sep=';') as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        # get X and y from chunk
        loss, mae = model.evaluate(X, y)
        # ...
```

Can I save the MAE from each chunk of data and then average them out to point out that this value is the MAE of my model?

P.S. I understand I can use Keras' `predict()` to save the predictions and then calculate MAE myself, but I am curious about my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I save the MAE from each chunk of data and then average them ?

Yes.

This is perfectly fine.
Why?
Think about the metric's definition.

Caveat: We assume $k$ chunks of equal chunk size $cs$.
If that does not obtain, you could resort to weighted averaging.

Each of the $MAE_1$ .. $MAE_k$ metrics is `sum(map(abs, errors_within_chunk)) / cs`.

If we were on a giant-RAM machine, we could run with just a single "all" chunk
of size $k \times cs$.

You are proposing this summary metric, which makes perfect sense:

$$MAE_{summary} \equiv \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k MAE_i}{k}$$

$$= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{cs} \frac{| ~ errors_{i,j} ~ |}{cs} }{k}$$

$$= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k \times cs} | ~ errors_{i} ~ | }{k \times cs}$$

Notice that this does not generalize to all other error metrics.
For example, don't try doing this with RMSE.

Clearly median differs from mean.
But you may find median adequate to your needs
if you're using some alternate non-linear error metric.
Alternatively, write each absolute error out to
a .CSV file, and at the end have a post-processing
step compute the aggregate metric.